# Unir dos curvas nls en el mismo gráfico

Tags: r

Tengo dos bases de datos que valoran las veces que rumia en un día una vaca con calor (Q1) y sin calor (Q4).

Genero el mismo modelo sinoidal:

```
mod.RumiQ1 <-nls(Rumination ~ a + b*sin(c*Hour-d)+e*cos(f*Hour-g),data=datosQ1,start=list(a =23.5, b = 6, c=3.1, d=9, e=-2.5, f=0.8,g=1))
co<-coef(mod.RumiQ1 )
co
#co
# a b c d e f g
#23.13338 -4.33017 0.33730 97.53357 -5.14952 0.50374 -1.82722
```

Y lo dibujo con :

```
ggplot(datosQ1, aes(x=Hour, y=Rumination))+

 # geom_point()+

 geom_smooth(method="nls", se=FALSE,

              method.args=list(formula=y~ a + b*sin(c*x-d)+e*cos(f*x-g),

                               start=c(a=23.13338,b= -4.33017,c=  0.33730,d= 97.53357,e= -5.14952,  f=0.50374, g= -1.82722 )) )
```

Ahora utilizo los datos Q4 :

```
mod.RumiQ4 <-nls(Rumination ~ a + b*sin(c*Hour-d)+e*cos(f*Hour-g),data=datosQ4,start=list(a =22, b = 5, c=3, d=9, e=-3.3, f=1,g=1.5))
co<-coef(mod.RumiQ4 )
co
# a b c d e f g
#22.03420 0.88497 1.89659 -11.66763 -3.35122 1.08926 3.51036
```

Y lo dibujo con:

```
ggplot(datosQ4,

aes(x=Hour, y=Rumination))+

 # geom_point()+

 geom_smooth(method="nls", se=FALSE,

              method.args=list(formula=y~ a + b*sin(c*x-d)+e*cos(f*x-g),

                               start=c(a=22.03,b= 0.88,c=  1.89,d= -11,e= -3,  f=1.00, g= 3.51)) )
```

Me gustaría tener las dos curvas en el mismo dibujo para poder comparar las gráficas

¿Cómo lo hago?

Gracias !!!!

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta y su respuesta te pueden ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120437/plotear-o-graficar-varios-lm-o-nls-en-una-sola-gr%c3%a1fica

Answer (score 1):

Es posible graficar cada curva de forma independiente, si bien no es lo más natural para `ggplot` sin duda es posible:

Generamos dos fuentes de datos distintas, por ejemplo co `iris`

```
data1 <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]
data2 <- iris[iris$Species == "virginica",]
```

---

Gráficamos cada `data.frame` de forma independiente:

```
ggplot() +
  # Curva 1 para data1
  geom_smooth(data = data1,
              mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length,  y = Petal.Length),
              method = "nls", 
              formula = y ~ a * x + b, 
              se = FALSE,
              color = "blue",
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1))) +
  # Curva 2 para data2
  geom_smooth(data = data2,
              method = "nls", 
              mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length,  y = Petal.Length),
              formula = y ~ a * x + b, 
              se = FALSE,
              color = "red",
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 0.1, b = 0.1)))
```

---

En vez de configurar `data` y `mapping` a nivel global, es decir en la llamada a `ggplot()` lo hacemos a nivel del `geom` y así podemos usar dos `geom_smooth()` independientes.

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @pmoracho funcionó !!!! GRACIAS. Otra cuestión (perdón por abusar), sería posible añadir a las curvas los intervalos de confianza ????? No soy muy experto y llevaba tiempo buscando la cuestión que me has solucionado y esta que te planteo.

Comment: @CarlosMínguez, no se si te refieres a esto, prueba con `se = TRUE`.

Comment: @pmoracho, gracias de nuevo por perder tu tiempo intentando ayudarme. Ya intenté ese comando pero me devolvía:

Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Es raro ese mensaje de error, al  menos no parece producto del uso del parámetro, tendría que ver al menos el código que estás usando, y eventualmente  los datos, pero excedería el marco de esta pregunta. O creas una nueva pregunta, o con unos pocos puntos más podría plantear el problema de forma más desestructurada en el [chat]

Comment: He intentado entrar en algún chat pero  poner que necesito un 20 de reputación

Comment: Si, por eso te decía que con unos pocos puntos que ganes (ya tienes 11) deberías poder.  El chat es lo mejor para plantear cuestiones de forma más desestructurada, con alguna actividad que hagas, por ejemplo en las colas de revisión puede ganar rápidamente esos puntos. Saludos.

Comment: Por si a alguien le interesa encontré la solución en :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976102/ggplot-fit-a-curve-geom-smooth-method-nls-with-ci95-bands
Gracias @pmoracho